# How to write static resource file in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working with a spring boot application. Client application will generate a static folder which will have all the static files like js and lib files. Along with these files I need to add few js files into the static folder(src/main/resources).

Right now I am using file Java.io. `fileutil.copyInputstream` which working fine in the eclipse. But, while running the jar file "src/main/resources" path is not identifying. How can I achieve this.
Code I am using now to create the file into resources folder

```
File = new File("src/main/resources/static/lib/" + resourceFile.getName() );
                                if (!tFile.exists()) {
//content I am getting from the db
                                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile( content.getStream() , File);
                                }
```

Comment: "static resource file" ? static application? what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: You want to add/replace static resource files *at runtime*? If so, then they are not truly *static*, but *dynamic*, and they shouldn't be stored in `src/main/resources`. Instead, they should maybe be stored in a database, e.g. a NoSQL database, or some external folder, i.e. a folder outside the project folder and definitely outside the `src` folder, because there are no such folder in a deployed application.